# looking for a name of a type of sentence that uses names of things

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when you create a sentence made mostly of names, places or things?

An example being

> After waking from (sleeping with sirens) i realized today would be (A day to remember) because it was (may days parade).

The things in parentheses are the names of metal bands.

Comment: Please take help in composing the question with proper capitalization. Good Luck.

Comment: I do not think there's a name for even a sentence mostly with names/ nouns.

Comment: The effort put into proper capitalization and termination, reflects the disinterest in getting an actual answer.

Comment: A play on words.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I tend to agree. I can however not let it just sit there...

Comment: @Mazura - A word on playing.

Answer (score -1):

It is a [nomer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomer); nomer: to name (give a name to),
to name (cite, make reference to)
(reflexive) to be called (have a certain name).

Comment: The word you are proposing, as verified by the link you provided, is a verb from the French language and in any case refers to the act of naming.